# Octave error: can't perform indexing operations for <unknown type> type

Tags: matlab, octave, sparse-matrix

I have an octave/Matlab function like this.

```
function [z] = baseline_als(y, lam, p, niter)
    L = size(y);
    D = sparse(diff(eye(L), 2));
    w = ones(L);
    for i = 1:niter
        W = sparse.spdiags(w, 0, L, L); %error comes here
        Z = W + lam * dot(D,transpose(D));
        % z = spsolve(Z, w*y);
        z= Z\(w*y);
        w = p * (y > z) + (1-p) * (y < z);
    end % End of For loop
end % End of function
```

I am calling this like this (in other file),

```
z = baseline_als(X,1000,0.00001,20)
plot(z)
```

Where X is 1D vector.

I have referred documentation from [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/accessing-sparse-matrices.html). But could not figure out this error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Should probably just be `W = spdiags(w, 0, L, L);`

Comment: getting this error than `error: spdiags: mx_el_le: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 131x131, op2 is 1x2)`

Comment: What is the size of `y`? Also, `w` should be a vector since your second argument is a scalar (i.e. `0`) and your third and fourth arguments also need to be scalars so maybe `L(1)` and `L(2)`...

Comment: `size(y)
ans =

   131     1
`

Comment: Then `W = spdiags(w, 0, L(1), L(2))` will be pretty pointless, what are the dimensions you were expecting for `W`? Maybe you wanted `W = spdiags(w, 0, L(1), L(1))`, which I'm actually fairly sure is the as `W = spdiags(w)`

Comment: If I use `W = spdiags(w)`, I get error in next to next line(This step `z= Z\(w*y);`)  as `error: baseline_als: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 131x1, op2 is 131x1)`

Comment: you need to sort out your matrix dimensions. I'm not going to debug your code for you line by line. Either transpose one of your vectors or use `.*`, it really depends on what you're doing. Every error you have had so far is because of matrix dimensions, please debug your code and check what the dimensions of each variable is line by line. You should know what dimensions they should be if you understand your own code and thus you should be able to spot which are wrong and then fix them accordingly.